# Access denied while deleting an entity

Tags: entities, 8

This is my Config entity:

```
 * @ConfigEntityType(
 *   id = "myentity",
 *   label = @Translation("My Entity"),
 *   controllers = {
 *     "storage" = "Drupal\Core\Config\Entity\ConfigEntityStorage",
 *     "list_builder" = "Drupal\mymodule\Controller\MyEntityListBuilder",
 *     "form" = {
 *       "default" = "Drupal\mymodule\Form\MyEntityForm",
 *       "delete" = "Drupal\mymodule\Form\MyEntityDeleteForm",
 *     },
 *   },
 *   admin_permission = "administer mymodule",
 *   config_prefix = "myentity",
 *   entity_keys = {
 *     "id" = "id",
 *     "label" = "name",
 *     "url" = "url",
 *     "status" = "status"
 *   },
 *   links = {
 *     "canonical" = "mymodule.myentity_info",
 *     "add-form" = "mymodule.myentity_add",
 *     "edit-form" = "mymodule.myentity_edit",
 *     "delete-form" = "mymodule.myentity_delete",
 *   }
 * )
 */
```

The `MyEntityDeleteForm`:

```
/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\mymodule\Form\MyEntityDeleteForm.
 */

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Database\Connection;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityConfirmFormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Url;

/**
 * Defines a confirmation form for deletion of a custom menu.
 */
class MyEntityDeleteForm extends EntityConfirmFormBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getQuestion() {
    return t('Are you sure you want to delete the myentity %title?', array('%title' => $this->entity->label()));
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submit(array $form, array &$form_state) {
    $this->entity->delete();
    drupal_set_message($this->t('The entity %title has been deleted.', array('%label' => $this->entity->label())));
    $form_state['redirect_route'] = $this->getCancelRoute();
  }

  public function getConfirmText() {
    return $this->t('Delete');
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getCancelRoute() {
    return $this->entity->urlInfo('canonical');
  }
}
```

The route defined in `routing.yml`:

```
mymodule.myentity_delete:
  path: '/admin/config/search/mymodule/myentity/{myentity}/delete'
  defaults:
    _entity_form: 'mymodule_myentity.delete'
  requirements:
    _entity_access: 'mymodule_myentity'
```

I'm getting this error while trying to delete the entity:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityAccessCheck->access() (line 46 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityAccessCheck.php).
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityAccessCheck->access(Object, Object, Object)
call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
Drupal\Core\Access\AccessManager->performCheck('access_check.entity', Object, Object, Object)
Drupal\Core\Access\AccessManager->checkAll(Array, Object, Object, Object)
Drupal\Core\Access\AccessManager->check(Object, Object, Object)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\AccessSubscriber->onKernelRequestAccessCheck(Object, 'kernel.request', Object)
call_user_func(Array, Object, 'kernel.request', Object)
Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch(Array, 'kernel.request', Object)
Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request', Object)
Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request', Object)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1)
Drupal\Core\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object)
```

And this message on the page:

```
Access denied
You are not authorized to access this page.
```

Comment: The message you've got there isn't an exception (it's just a notice). We'll need to see the exception message to help

Comment: @Clive: Please see my updated question. I made a few edits.

Comment: @Mołot: I'm taking help from here: https://www.drupal.org/node/1809494

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [`EntityAccessCheck::access()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!EntityAccessCheck.php/function/EntityAccessCheck%3A%3Aaccess/8) you'll see this:

```
$requirement = $route->getRequirement('_entity_access');
list($entity_type, $operation) = explode('.', $requirement);
```

The second line is causing the notice, and your access check to subsequently fail. Basically, the access method is expecting (requiring, in fact) your permission to contain an entity type and access operation, separated by a `.`.

If you take the node module's [routing file](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!node!node.routing.yml/8) as an example:

```
node.delete_confirm:
  path: '/node/{node}/delete'
  defaults:
    _entity_form: 'node.delete'
    _title: 'Delete'
  requirements:
    _entity_access: 'node.delete'
  options:
    _node_operation_route: TRUE
```

I would suggest you just need to change your route to match:

```
mymodule.myentity_delete:
  path: '/admin/config/search/mymodule/myentity/{myentity}/delete'
  defaults:
    _entity_form: 'mymodule_myentity.delete'
  requirements:
    _entity_access: 'mymodule_myentity.delete'
```

Comment: I'd already done this. It didn't show any warnings/errors but simply shows an "Access denied page".

Comment: Don't forget you'll need to rebuild the cache after altering the route..

Comment: Yeah. I did that. But still, the "Access denied" page.

Comment: Presumably the user you're trying to delete the entity which doesn't have access permissions to do so